# In the group $\mathbb {Z}_n $ prove that $ \langle [k]_n\rangle = \langle [d]_n\rangle$ where $d$ is the gcd$(k,n)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $k,n$ be two positve integer.  Define $d$ to be their greatest common divisor
in the group $\mathbb {Z}_n $ prove that $ \langle [k]_n\rangle = \langle [d]_n\rangle$

The best I was able to do is write $k=\text{id}$ where gcd$(i,m)=1$ something makes me want to just toss the i for some reason but i cant think of any reason to justify it.

I tried writing $ e, k^1, k^2 ,..., k^{o(k)-1} $ but it didnt get me anywhere I would like to say that $ [\text{id}]_n = [d]_n $ cause then id be done but its not coming to me how to do so

Comment: FYI: you can use \langle and \rangle for $\langle$ and $\rangle$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll write $(\Bbb{Z}_n,+)=\{0,1,\cdots, n-1\}$ and use addition notation, so $e=n=2n=0$ etc. For simplicity, we'll drop the $[\cdot]_n$ since $n$ is fixed.

Example: In $\Bbb{Z}_6$, $e=0=\pm6=\pm12$, $1=-5=7$, $3+8=11=5$ etc. You can check that

$\langle 0\rangle=\{0\}$

$\langle 1\rangle=\langle 5\rangle=\Bbb{Z}_6$

$\langle 2\rangle=\langle 4\rangle=\{0,2,4\}$

$\langle 3\rangle=\{0,3\}$ etc.

Now, returning to the general case for $\Bbb{Z}_n$, $d=\text{gcd}(k,n)$ means that there is an $m\in\Bbb{Z}$ with $k=dm$, so $\langle k\rangle\leq\langle d\rangle$.

$d=\text{gcd}(k,n)$ also means, by Bezout's identity, that there are $a,b\in\Bbb{Z}$ with $d=ak+bn$. This gives $\langle d\rangle=\langle ak+bn\rangle=\langle ak\rangle$, so $\langle d\rangle\leq\langle k\rangle$.